# Interação do VBA com Internet Explorer e utilização do getelementsbyclassname não funciona

Tags: vba

venho tentando criar um código que me faz entrar no Internet Explorer(ie), ir no site do yahoo finance, adicionar minha pesquisa de ações e buscar, porém a parte de buscar não vai.

O meu código é esse:

```
linha_ticker = 2
ticker = Sheets("Ibovespa").Cells(linha_ticker, 3)

'variável com fórmula deve ser atribuida por meio do SET
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.navigate "https://br.financas.yahoo.com/"
ie.Visible = True

'ação para só prosseguir caso a página esteja completamente carregada
Do While ie.busy And ie.readystate <> "READYSTATE_COMPLETE"
    DoEvents
Loop

'procurar na pagina ie o input de valor 0 e colocar nele o que está na variável ativo
ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = ticker
'clicar em buscar
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("Bgc($linkColor) Bgc($linkActiveColor):h Fz(s) Fw(500) H(35px) Py(0px) Px(15px) W(80px) Bdrstend(2px) Bdrsbend(2px) Ta(c)")(0).Click
```

E o html do botão clicar é esse:

```
<button type="button" id="search-button" class="Bgc($linkColor) Bgc($linkActiveColor):h Fz(s) Fw(500) H(35px) Py(0px) Px(15px) W(80px) Bdrstend(2px) Bdrsbend(2px) Ta(c)" data-reactid="63">
<svg class="H(20px) W(20px) Va(m)! Fill(white)! Stk(white) Cur(p)" width="20" style="fill:#000;stroke:#000;stroke-width:0;vertical-align:bottom;" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-icon="search" data-reactid="64">
<path d="M9 3C5.686 3 3 5.686 3 9c0 3.313 2.686 6 6 6s6-2.687 6-6c0-3.314-2.686-6-6-6m13.713 19.713c-.387.388-1.016.388-1.404 0l-7.404-7.404C12.55 16.364 10.85 17 9 17c-4.418 0-8-3.582-8-8 0-4.42 3.582-8 8-8s8 3.58 8 8c0 1.85-.634 3.55-1.69 4.905l7.403 7.404c.39.386.39 1.015 0 1.403" data-reactid="65">
</path>
</svg>
</button>
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Você não passou exatamente o comportamento do erro, o que dificulta um pouco a análise (por exemplo: ele preenche o ticker e depois não faz nada? Ou ele realmente dá um erro?).

Também não dá para analisar a página. Pode ter uma `iframe`, o que muda tudo, pois é necessário referenciar os documentos da iframe. Pode ter outro objeto com essa mesma classe antes, então o botão não seria o item 0 da coleção.

Enfim, sem maiores informações, considerando que o botão tem um atributo `ID`, eu tentaria usar outro método para referenciar o botão:

```
ie.document.getElementsById("search-button").Click
```

Espero que funcione.